# Protocol on Wireshark says LLC

Tags: wireshark, udp

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/24fPH.png)

A theoretical question may be.

I have created UDP traffic across my network involving client and Server. When i ping the server and monitor the data using wireshark, it says protocol is LLC. Anybody please explain why doesnt the protocol section on wireshark say UDP as I created UDP traffic?

Comment: Did you forget to include the IP header? Please show the whole Wireshark screenshot.

Comment: Just updated now.. To give an intro, I am sendng customised messgaes using UDP protocol over a private network between 2 masters and a slave.IP wih .175 is the client, and .51 are the servers

Answer (score 1):

The Wireshark Protocol column displays only the highest layer protocol, as higher layer protocols overwrite the column data populated by any lower layer protocols.  That is why you see LLC instead of UDP.

As for why Wireshark thinks this is LLC at all, that's because the [LLC dissector registers with UDP ports 12000-12004 by default](https://code.wireshark.org/review/gitweb?p=wireshark.git;a=blob;f=epan/dissectors/packet-llc.c;h=3eaf473bdc84e4b96a4f6a873b32d7d592357379;hb=HEAD#l893) per [RFC 2353](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2353), and your image shows a UDP destination port of 12000, which falls within this range.

If you don't want the payload dissected as LLC, then you can either:

- Choose a different UDP port outside the range of 12000-12004
- Disable the LLC dissector (Wireshark: *Analyze -> Enabled Protocols -> LLC -> [deselect]*)
- Modify the LLC port range preference to exclude port 12000 (Wireshark: *Edit -> Preferences -> Protocols -> LLC -> UDP port(s) 12001-12004*)

Answer (score 0):

Ping uses
[Internet Control Message Protocol (ICMP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Control_Message_Protocol).

This is a protocol in its own right that is apart from the protocols of UDP or TCP.
ICMP is based on IP and operates in the network-layer protocol.
There is no TCP or UDP port number associated with ICMP packets, as these numbers
are associated with the higher transport layer.

[Logical link control (LLC)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_link_control)
operates in the upper sublayer of the data link layer (layer 2) of the seven-layer
[OSI model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model).

As such I would think that Wireshark is in error when marking the ICMP ping package
as LLC. But in any case, it couldn't be marked as UDP since it is not that.
It's possible that you might have missed the mention of ICMP in the package dump.

For more details, see
[What are the differences between TCP, UDP, and ICMP packet types?](https://www.pingplotter.com/wisdom/article/packet-type-differences)

Comment: thank you for the clarification.

Comment: Based on screenshot, it seems to me that OP is using 'ping' as a general verb here, and not specifically referring to the ICMP-based `ping` tool at all. (I've seen the term applied to similar purpose packets at various different layers.)

Comment: @user1686: In the screenshot that was added, I can see that the packet marked LLC is analyzed as "Protocol: UDP (17)". Based on this I propose the following theory: Wireshark is capturing UDP packets, but does the capturing on the LLC data link layer. The UDP tag is added by its analysis of the contents of the packet. This will explain the two tags, LLC & UDP, on this one package.

Comment: Thanks for the clarity @harrymc :)                                                                                    
Also another question.. could you tell me what does it mean when the information says-- "SSAP ISO Network Layer(unofficial?) Command"?

Comment: This relates to Source [Service Access Point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_Access_Point) (SSAP). It is used to identify which protocol handler should process an incoming frame. There exists also DSAP for Destination.

Comment: If my answer was helpful, please consider marking it as accepted (tick the V sign), or/and upvote (the up-arrow sign).