# Reassemble Wireshark WiFi captured LLC packets into original message

Tags: wireless-networking, wireshark

I have the following setup within my own WiFi network: one machine (A) connected to my WiFi (which connects to the internet), and one machine (B) running Wireshark, with a WiFi adapter in monitoring mode capturing packets from A.

B has already deauth A (i.e. obtaining full WPA2 handshakes). And with the WiFi password, B can fully decrypt all WiFi packets in and out of A, on Wireshark.

I notice that the majority of these packets are of protocol LLC, which is for UDP. Now, say I log into my Gmail on A, and send out an email with a short text message. What would be the process to capture and reassemble this text message on B? Or is this objective even possible?

Comment: CommView offers some ability to re-assemble packets. I use this. Try the trial version to see if it fits your needs.

Comment: Are you sure decryption is actually working? LLC is extremely rare on modern networks (and has nothing to do with UDP, by the way), but when a packet analyzer tries to parse an encrypted packet as if it wasn't encrypted, it often looks like LLC. So seeing lots of "LLC" packets in a monitor mode packet trace is usually an indicator that you're not actually decrypting the packets.

Comment: @Spiff This thread [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1572282/protocol-on-wireshark-says-llc) explains the ```LLC``` protocol in Wireshark

Comment: Okay, so back in the 1990's IBM wanted to tunnel LLC inside UDP for the sake of IBM's old proprietary "SNA" networking scheme, and did so on ports 12000-12004. But if the traffic you're capturing doesn't show you IP headers and UDP headers with UDP ports in that range of 5 ports, then that thread is not applicable here. If you see a bunch of random LLC SSAP/DSAP stuff, with no IP addresses, then you're trying to parse encrypted frames as if they were unencrypted.

Comment: Now that you have explained, it does seem I am looking at a bunch of encrypted packets. Will update this question once I investigate further.

Answer (score 0):

See the Wireshark manual chapter
[7.8. Packet Reassembly](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/ChAdvReassemblySection.html).

This is what it says :

> For some of the network protocols Wireshark knows of, a mechanism is
> implemented to find, decode and display these chunks of data.
> Wireshark will try to find the corresponding packets of this chunk,
> and will show the combined data as additional tabs in the “Packet
> Bytes” pane (for information about this pane. See [Section 3.20, “The
> “Packet Bytes”
> Pane”](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/ChUsePacketBytesPaneSection.html)).
>
> Reassembly might take place at several protocol layers, so it’s
> possible that multiple tabs in the “Packet Bytes” pane appear.
>
> **Note**
>
> You will find the reassembled data in the last packet of the chunk.

Comment: Thanks, I did read this page. But this only explained the reassembling of data in one packet. It does not explain how to reassemble multiple packets to get back the original message, when the message is chopped into multiple packets before being sent.

Comment: You will have to better define what is "message" and using which protocol.